# What is the best phrase or word thad descibes that bidding has started?

Tags: single-word-requests

My native language is Swedish. And I work as a webdeveloper. And at the moment I am working on a real estate website written in English.

So I would like to know, what is the best word or phrase that describes that bidding of a property has started, when it is writen as a "status" of the object.

Could I use

> "Bidding has begun"

or is thera a better word or phrase?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: So there is no better word, when you talk about the status of the object?  :)

Comment: Well if 'bidding' is itself the status, you can say 'started' or 'in progress'.

Comment: Is the property being sold in the UK or US?

Comment: It is in the US :)

Comment: I think the bidding has "opened".  When it's over it's "closed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard English, more often that not, doesn't have words for very specific events like this one. I can't find a single word for you to use, but it would be beneficial to condense your statement to this:

> Bidding started

This is possibly the closest you'll get while still being as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Bidding is *open*.  Later on, bidding is *closed*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check with professionals in the relevant country. In the UK, the word "bid" would suggest that the property was being sold by auction, but that is not how most properties are sold in the UK.

In the UK, "*n* offers have been received" (where *n* is a number) seems right (but I am not a professional). Buyers make "offers" to buy and name the price they are prepared to pay. The seller can accept any of the offers, not necessarily the one with the highest price. Offers to buy are normally made "subject to contract" and are not legally binding until a contract (written by a lawyer) has been signed and exchanged. http://hoa.org.uk/advice/guides-for-homeowners/i-am-buying/making-an-offer-and-haggling-over-the-price/

In an auction, the auctioneer chooses a price that he or she will accept, and buyers "bid" to accept that price. The auctioneer then raises the price until only one "bidder" is left. The "final bid" is a legally binding contract, even though you don't know, at the time when you make the bid, whether or not it will be the final one.

Comment: Okay. If I might ask, are you from UK or America?

Comment: I'm from the UK. I don't know if the terminology is different in the USA